# If... Else... logic on Button_Click not working

Tags: c#, wpf, logic

I can't understand why my If... Else logic is not working.

What I am trying to archive is that when the user clicks the button, it will first check if the value of page is less than or equal to the length of the array then it increments the page variable and runs the DisplayPath method else it sets the page variable to the length of the array.

When I run the app, and click the button, as soon as it increments past the length of the array, it crashes.

```
    private string[] filePaths;
    private int page;

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (page <= filePaths.Length)
        {
            page++;
            DisplayPath(page);
        }
        else
        {
            page = filePaths.Length;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filePaths is a zero based array, change it to

```
    private string[] filePaths;
private int page;

private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (page < filePaths.Length-1)
    {
        DisplayPath(++page);
    }
    else
    {
        page = filePaths.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I set the page variable to 0 in another part of the code.

Comment: Thats not the point, I imagine DisplayPath is using your array like filePaths[page].  If page == filePaths.Length this will blow up as the largest index in the array is filePaths.Length-1

Comment: Okay thanks! Understood. But I have to change it to if (page < filePaths.Length - 1). Then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Since `filePaths` is a zero based array;

```
if (page < filePaths.Length)
{
    DisplayPath(++page);
}
```

> Arrays are zero indexed: an array with **n** elements is indexed from **0** to
>   **n-1**.

Answer (score 1):

You should test for less than filePaths.Length

```
  if (page < filePaths.Length)
```

Array starts at index zero and could be indexed to Length - 1

Answer (score -1):

It should be `page < filePaths.Length -1` since you are adding to `page` **before** `DisplayPath()`
Because of that page will point to a non existing place in the array `filePaths`